# Second discount code

Tags: price, discount, multiple

We use Magento for factoring (sending invoices to 3rd party).

Here's a scenario of *our* customer, who uses our Magento implementation to, in his turn, invoice *his* customer for a paint job (taxes are omitted in this example):
Our customer starts off with adding an initiate cost for the painting of $100.
He then goes on adding 13 hours of wall painting; $20 x 13 hours = $260.
Then for some reasons he adds a discount for 3 hours, which he needs to show explicitly, so he adds a 3 hours discount to the invoice item list: -$20 x 3 hours = -$60.
Finally he adds a campaign discount of 50% for the whole invoice.

The cart would then look like this:

```
Material and travelling: $100.00 x 01 =  $100.00
Painting:                 $20.00 x 13 =  $260.00
Discount:                -$20.00 x 03 =  -$60.00
=================================================
Campaign discount:                         50.00%
=================================================
Total:                                   $300.00
Campaign discount:                      -$150.00
Grand total to pay:                      $150.00
```

We're already using the native discount system for the whole cart, ie the campaign discount, for this invoice and need to implement a second discount which is set for the product/work, ie the painting work.

Also this should be done in code as the front end is very much NOT web shop like in user interface.
Something like this:

```
$quote()->secondDiscount($secondDiscountCode);
```

So. Is this possible? With an extension or even without an extension?

This tip is very helpful, but doesn't really apply as we're using a third party extension for the checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138237/magento-multiple-coupon-codes-for-one-order-without-extension.
So no need pointing us there ;)

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial to implement an import duty tax that applied to the whole order:

http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-development-add-total-row-checkout/

Other resources forgot about the templates, the credit memos and other scenarios where all the sub totals need to be shown.

Obviously you are not wanting a tax, but a discount. It all works the same.

I also had to experiment a while getting my sub-totals the way I wanted them so everything including the shipping was part of the charge, presumably you will need a different sub totals order to me to have the shipping added on after the discount lines are applied.

Comment: This looks promising! But before I dig into it, is the solution ok with negative prices or percentages? Or is negative prices / percentages a whole other thing to battle?